# Error in spark installation on window

Tags: apache-spark, installation, pyspark

I installed spark on my computer(window 10) when i ran spark\bin\spark-shell.the shell execute successfully but when i run spark\bin\pyspark it give error:
Import-Error: No module named site.

Comment: what version of python do you have ?

Comment: i have python version 2.7.11